# Type 'Observable<ArrayBuffer>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<HttpResponse<User>>'

Tags: angular, typescript, api, authentication, rxjs

good evening, I'm trying to set up a authentication service and the login function keeps showing this error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<HttpResponse>'.   Type 'ArrayBuffer' is missing the
> following properties from type 'HttpResponse': body, type,
> clone, headers, and 4 more.

function is as follows:

```
  login(user:User): Observable<HttpResponse<User>>{
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this.apiUrl}/login`, user, {observe: Response});
  }
```

the user model interface is :

```
export interface User {
    username: string;
    password:string;
}
```

and I'm calling this function is my login component:

```
onLogin(user: User):void{
  this.subs.add(
  this.authService.login(user).subscribe(
    (response) =>{
      this.authService.addTokenToCache(response.headers.get('Jwt-Token') || '{}');
      // this.authService.addUserToCache(response.body|| '{}');
      this.router.navigateByUrl("/home");
      this.showLoading=false;
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse)=>{
      alert(error.message);
      this.showLoading=false;
    }
  ))
}
```

how exactly can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually now using the fetch api interface `Response` and that is why you are getting this error. The `observe` options are `'body'`, `'events'` or `'response'`. Notice the lowercase `r` in response and that it is also a string. That being said, your code should be:

```
return this.http.post<User>(`${this.apiUrl}/login`, user, {observe: 'response'});
```

Comment: thank you this works, I should've payed attention to the case sensitivity.